# terraform.apply InvalidParameterException: The following supplied instance types do not exist: [m4.large]

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-eks

I have the below `cluster.tf` file in my `EC2` instance (type: `t3.micro`):

```
locals {
  cluster_name = "my-eks-cluster"
}

module "vpc" {
  source = "git::https://git@github.com/reactiveops/terraform-vpc.git?ref=v5.0.1"

  aws_region = "eu-north-1"
  az_count   = 3
  aws_azs    = "eu-north-1a, eu-north-1b, eu-north-1c"

  global_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
  }
}

module "eks" {
  source       = "git::https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks.git?ref=v16.1.0"
  cluster_name = local.cluster_name
  cluster_version = "1.17"
  vpc_id       = module.vpc.aws_vpc_id
  subnets      = module.vpc.aws_subnet_private_prod_ids

  node_groups = {
    eks_nodes = {
      desired_capacity = 3
      max_capacity     = 3
      min_capaicty     = 3

      instance_type = "t3.micro"
    }
  }

  manage_aws_auth = false
}
```

But when I'm running the command `terraform.apply` I get this exception:

```
Error: error creating EKS Node Group (my-eks-cluster/my-eks-cluster-eks_nodes-divine-pig): InvalidParameterException: The following supplied instance types do not exist: [m4.large]
```

I tried to google it but couldn't find a solution for it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't worked previously before with AWS modules but in `modules/node_groups` on that GitHub repo link it looks like you may need to set `node_group_defaults`.

Reason why is that the `If unset` column for the `instance type` row says that the value in `[var.workers_group_defaults[instance_type]]` will be used.

That default value is located in the root [local.tf](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/master/local.tf) and has a value of `m4.large` so maybe that instance type is not supported in your AWS region?

Not sure of how to fix this completely but may help with starting to troubleshoot.

Comment: Indeed changing the value in `local.trf` to `t3.micro` solved the issue! tnx!

Comment: @rel.foo.fighters What about your min, max, and desired_capacity fields? Those look like they also will take in default values from that local.tf file for the workers_group_defaults.